# Alfresco JavaScript, set custom type property, when file is uploaded to site

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I would like to write a JavaScript script that can set a sequence number property of a document automatically, when it's type is changed to my custom type. The sequentNum property must be different from the other document's sequentNum property.

How can i get the document, and how can i set its property?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look into Policies and Behaviors. You can register a JavaScript which will be executed on "OnSetNodeTypePolicy". 
Jeff Potts created a great Tutorial you should take a look into: [Re-implementing the behavior in JavaScript](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/behaviors/tutorial/tutorial.html#re-implementing-the-behavior-in-javascript)

Be careful how to implement the logic for your sequence next value. Don't use search since it doesn't guarantee latest value. We used a separate node for that issue in a very early implementation where we set a maxSequence property but now we use a custom service for that approach (multithrading, scalability).

Hint: If you don't already know: You can put your xxx-context.xml Sprint bean config into tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/ instead of creating an amp file to make it easier for quick tests

Comment: Awesome! This tutorial was super useful! Thank you very much :)